# Javafx Google maps Marker by altitude and longitude

Tags: java, google-maps

I'm working on a Javafx project, I wanted to integrate google maps , and worked well, the problem now is that I want to display marker by getting the event address with geocoding and worked also, but the marker for now, I'm just getting it statically.

```
@Override
public void mapInitialized() {


       geocodingService = new GeocodingService();
  geocodingService.geocode(evs.getAdresse(),
            (GeocodingResult[] results, com.lynden.gmapsfx.service.geocoding.GeocoderStatus status) -> {
                LatLong l = new LatLong(results[0].getGeometry().getLocation().getLatitude(),
                        results[0].getGeometry().getLocation().getLongitude());
               markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(l)
                        .title(evs.getNomAnnonce())
                        .visible(true);


            });
             LatLong annonceLocation = new LatLong(36.858900, 10.196500);     
    //Set the initial properties of the map.
    MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions();

    mapOptions.center(new LatLong(36.858900, 10.196500))
       .mapType(MapTypeIdEnum.ROADMAP)
            .overviewMapControl(true)
            .panControl(true)
            .rotateControl(true)
            .scaleControl(true)
            .streetViewControl(true)
            .zoomControl(true)
            .zoom(12);

    map = mapView.createMap(mapOptions);

    //Add markers to the map


    MarkerOptions markerOptions1 = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions1.position(annonceLocation);




    Marker AnnonceMarker = new Marker(markerOptions1);


    map.addMarker( AnnonceMarker );


    InfoWindowOptions infoWindowOptions = new InfoWindowOptions();
    infoWindowOptions.content(evs.getDescription()+"<h2>"+evs.getNomAnnonce() +"</h2>"
                            + evs.getDateDebut()
                            + evs.getDateDebut());

    InfoWindow fredWilkeInfoWindow = new InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
    fredWilkeInfoWindow.open(map, AnnonceMarker);
}
```

Result :

[gmaps result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOJku.png)

Comment: How is this result different than what you want?

Comment: As you can see in my code, I'm setting the marker's position statically, I want it to be displayed dynamically getting the   (LatLong l ) values.

Comment: Can you try passing your dynamically generated location variable to `annonceLocation`, which you use to position the marker?

Comment: But what about this  `LatLong annonceLocation = new LatLong(36.858900, 10.196500);`